# DropDown menu to slide back after a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created a dropdown menu on the mobile version of my website using this code:

https://codepen.io/plavookac/pen/qomrMw

The problem is that after you click one of the links the dropdown menu stays open but i'd like it to slide back. (My website is on a single page with sliding anchor links).

I added the following script, which makes the menu to slide back as I want but then I can't open it again, as the menu toggle doesn't change back.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.sidebarMenuInner li a').on("click", function(){
        $('#sidebarMenu').slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
```

Any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu appears when the `checkbox` is `checked`. You can change the `checked` attribute ( prop ) of the input so the menu will close. And so the functionality stays the same.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.sidebarMenuInner li a').on("click", function(){
      $('#openSidebarMenu').prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

I changed the `href` of first `a` so you can test it without going to another location

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.sidebarMenuInner li a').on("click", function(){
      $('#openSidebarMenu').prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}
.header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #FC466B;
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px!important;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.mainInner{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.mainInner div{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.25px;
}
#sidebarMenu {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    transform: translateX(-250px);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FC466B 0%, #3F5EFB 100%);
}
.sidebarMenuInner{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li{
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
}
.sidebarIconToggle {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 22px;
    left: 15px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
}
.spinner {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.horizontal {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.diagonal.part-1 {
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
.diagonal.part-2 {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: 8px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: -9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
  <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>
  <div id="sidebarMenu">
    <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
      <li>Jelena Jovanovic <span>Web Developer</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://instagram.com/plavookac" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/plavookac" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDfZM0IK6RBgud8HYGFXAJg" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/plavookac/" target="_blank">Linkedin</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='center' class="main center">
    <div class="mainInner">
      <div>PURE CSS SIDEBAR TOGGLE MENU</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainInner">
      <div>PURE CSS SIDEBAR TOGGLE MENU</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainInner">
      <div>PURE CSS SIDEBAR TOGGLE MENU</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @ErikaBarichello glad i could help. Do no forget to rate/accept my answer. Thanks ! :d

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$('li > a').click(function(){
    $('.sidebarIconToggle').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simply do `$('#openSidebarMenu').click();` instead of `$('#sidebarMenu').slideUp();`

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback function of `slideUp()` to `slideDown` when finished. And uncheck the checkbox which controls the behaviour of the menu.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.sidebarMenuInner li a').on("click", function(){
        $('#sidebarMenu').slideUp(function() {
          $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
          $('#sidebarMenu').slideDown();
        });
    });
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.sidebarMenuInner li a').on("click", function(){
        $('#sidebarMenu').slideUp(function() {
          $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
          $('#sidebarMenu').slideDown();
        });
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round');
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}
.header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #FC466B;
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px!important;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.mainInner{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.mainInner div{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.25px;
}
#sidebarMenu {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    transform: translateX(-250px);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FC466B 0%, #3F5EFB 100%);
}
.sidebarMenuInner{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li{
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50);
}
.sidebarMenuInner li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
}
.sidebarIconToggle {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 22px;
    left: 15px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
}
.spinner {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.horizontal {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.diagonal.part-1 {
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
.diagonal.part-2 {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: 8px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: -9px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
  <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>
  <div id="sidebarMenu">
    <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
      <li>Jelena Jovanovic <span>Web Developer</span></li>
      <li><a href="https://vanila.io" target="_blank">Company</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://instagram.com/plavookac" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/plavookac" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDfZM0IK6RBgud8HYGFXAJg" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/plavookac/" target="_blank">Linkedin</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='center' class="main center">
    <div class="mainInner">
      <div>PURE CSS SIDEBAR TOGGLE MENU</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainInner">
      <div>PURE CSS SIDEBAR TOGGLE MENU</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainInner">
      <div>PURE CSS SIDEBAR TOGGLE MENU</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```